# nginx - bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I've got a reverse proxy with 5 server configs set up, however since the start it's always been complaining about not being able to listen on the ports I specified so the server has been unable to start.

I've tried a few things:

- Split config into multiple files inside `sites-available` and creating symlinks to `sites-enabled`
- Delete the `listen` property and allowing it to fall back to defaults
- Changing the ports to `ipv6only=on` - this caused an error
- Changing the ports to `[::]:80`
- Changing the ports so that there are no conflicts, ie, `80`, `81`, `82`, etc.

Using `netstat` I can see that nothing is running on the ports I need, and when I run `nginx -t` I get a successful output saying syntax is ok and nginx.conf test is successful.

This is my `nginx` output:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:82 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:83 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:84 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

Does anybody know why this is caused? Thanks in advance

Here's my server configs:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name hac-staging-proxy.redant.cloud;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://195.219.8.212/;
                proxy_set_header Host www.uat2prd.halfordsautocentres.com;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }
}

server {
        listen 81;
        server_name halfords-c1-staging-proxy.redant.cloud;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://195.219.8.206/;
                proxy_set_header Host www.c1.uat2prd.halfordsautocentres.com;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }

}

server {
        listen 82;
        server_name halfords-c2-staging-proxy.redant.cloud;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://195.219.8.206/;
                proxy_set_header Host www.c2.uat2prd.halfordsautocentres.com;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }

}

server {
        listen 83;
        server_name halfords-staging-proxy.redant.cloud;

        proxy_redirect http://www.uat2prd.halfords.com http://halfords-staging-proxy.redant.cloud;
        proxy_redirect https://www.uat2prd.halfords.com https://halfords-staging-proxy.redant.cloud;

        location / {
                add_header Set-Cookie Experiment=FH;
                resolver 127.0.0.1;
                proxy_pass http://www.uat2prd.halfords.com;
                # sub_filter_types *;
                sub_filter 'www.uat2prd.halfords.com' 'halfords-staging-proxy.redant.cloud';
                sub_filter 'www.c1.uat2prd.halfords.com' 'halfords-c1-staging-proxy.redant.cloud';
                sub_filter 'www.c2.uat2prd.halfords.com' 'halfords-c2-staging-proxy.redant.cloud';
                sub_filter_once off;
                proxy_set_header Set-Cookie Experiment=FH;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }
}

server {
        listen 84;
        server_name halfords-staging-proxy.redant.cloud2;

        proxy_redirect https://www.uat2prd.halfords.com https://halfords-staging-proxy.redant.cloud;
        proxy_redirect http://www.uat2prd.halfords.com http://halfords-staging-proxy.redant.cloud;

        ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/domain.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/domain.key;
        ssl_dhparam               /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "INTENTIONALLY REMOVED"
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                add_header Set-Cookie Experiment=FH;
                resolver 127.0.0.1;
                proxy_pass https://www.uat2prd.halfords.com;
                # proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                # sub_filter_types *;
                sub_filter 'www.uat2prd.halfords.com' 'halfords-staging-proxy.redant.cloud';
                sub_filter 'www.c1.uat2prd.halfords.com' 'halfords-c1-staging-proxy.redant.cloud';
                sub_filter 'www.c2.uat2prd.halfords.com' 'halfords-c2-staging-proxy.redant.cloud';
                sub_filter_once off;
                proxy_set_header Set-Cookie Experiment=FH;
                proxy_set_header Host www.uat2prd.halfords.com;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you have any chance to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a port that's needed by nginx, check and open it. It might work. Or just scan all the files inside of the nginx directory for port 98 it must have something to do with nginx configuration.